# Using Task.WaitAll(threads) is not blocking appropriately

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Threads
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action<int> TestingDelegate = (x321) => { Console.WriteLine(x321); };
            int x123 = Environment.ProcessorCount;

            MyParallelFor(0, 8, TestingDelegate);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void MyParallelFor(int inclusiveLowerBound, int exclusiveUpperBound, Action<int> body)
        {

            int size = exclusiveUpperBound - inclusiveLowerBound;
            int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int range = size / numProcs;

            var threads = new List<Task>(numProcs);
            for(int p = 0; p < numProcs; p++)
            {
                int start = p * range + inclusiveLowerBound;
                int end = (p == numProcs - 1) ? exclusiveUpperBound : start + range;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) body(i);
                });

            }

            Task.WaitAll(threads.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all, I implemented this code from the Patterns of Parallel Programming book and they do it using threads, I decided to rewrite it using the TPL library. The output below is what I get (of course it's random) however... I expect "Done!" to always be printed last. For some reason it is not doing that though. Why is it not blocking?

```
Done!
1
0
2
6
5
4
3
7
```

Comment: *Patterns of Parallel Programming* is a great book, but it's worth keeping in mind that it was written with .NET4.0 in mind. If you are targeting .NET4.5, try to steer clear of `Task.Factory.StartNew` (it has been superseded by `Task.Run` in the general case).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to rewrite it using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not assign any tasks to the `threads` list on which you are calling WaitAll, your tasks are started independently. you would create tasks and put the tasks in `threads` collection before you call `WaitAll`. You can find more how you would add the tasks in tasks list you have created in this MSDN documentation for [Task.WaitAll Method (Task[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

You code would be something like

```
threads.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ;
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

you are not adding task to your threads collection. So threads collection is empty. So there is no Tasks to wait for. Change code like this

```
threads.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) body(i);
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasons is quite simple: You are never adding anything to the `threads` List. You declare it and allocate space for `numProcs` entries, but you never call `threads.Add`.

Therefore the list is still empty and hence the `Task.WaitAll` doesn't wait on anything.